# I am passing variables in Pattern.compile() and .matcher() but not getting required output

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching, java.util.scanner

I wrote a program that asks the user for a target String and a pattern to be searched in it. It is intended to find the position of the matched pattern and how many times it is present in the target string. But it always shows no pattern was found even if the pattern is present in the target string.
I have written a function `searchPattern()` for it.

```java
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.regex.Matcher;
    import java.util.regex.Pattern;

    public class Main
    {
        private static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {

            String pattern,target;
            System.out.println("Enter Target String: ");
            pattern = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter pattern to be searched: ");
            target = sc.nextLine();
            searchPattern(pattern,target);
        }
        public static void searchPattern(String pattern,String target)
        {
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
            Matcher m = p.matcher(target);
            int count = 0;
            //if(!m.find())return;
            while (m.find())
            {
                count ++;
                System.out.println(m.start() + "--" + m.end() + "--" + m.group());
            }
            if (count == 0)
                System.out.println("Your pattern was not found in the target string");
            else
                System.out.println("Total occurrences of 'ab' are" + count);

        }
    }
```

It gives the following output:

```
Enter Target String: 
ababbab
Enter pattern to be searched: 
ab
Your pattern was not found in the target string
```

Even if 'ab' is present in the target String, why isn't this code working

Comment: The variables you're storing are reversed

Comment: Oh! what a fool i am!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're storing the target and pattern in the wrong variables

```
private static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String pattern, target;
    System.out.println("Enter Target String: ");
    target = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter pattern to be searched: ");
    pattern = sc.nextLine();
    searchPattern(pattern, target);
}

public static void searchPattern(String pattern, String target) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(target);
    int count = 0;
    while (m.find()) {
        count++;
        System.out.println(m.start() + "--" + m.end() + "--" + m.group());
    }
    if (count == 0) {
        System.out.println("Your pattern was not found in the target string");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Total occurrences of " + pattern + " are" + count);
    }
}
```